# Sum of digits of some number

Tags: c

for example, if I typed in 12345 then sum = 1+2+3+4+5
Using C
I used some kind of approach that I'm not sure about it and there is a problem with the line referred to down in the code

```
int i ;
int sum;
int individual;
int n;
printf("enter the number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i=0;i<5;++i){
  **indvidual=+n[i];**
  sum=+invidual;
}
printf("%d",sum)
return 0;
```

Comment: `+=` and `=+` are completely different things (the latter is in fact two things). And initialize your variables.

Comment: Are you sure that the incoming number will always have exactly 5 digits? It would perhaps be more useful to read it as an integer, then continuously add the last digit and divide by 10, until you're left with 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by 10 and see the remainder to obtain each digits.

Also you should use `+=`, not `=+`, to add things to variable and initialize the variables before using their values.

```
int i ;
int sum = 0; /* initialize */
int individual;
int n;
printf("enter the number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i=0;i<5;++i){
  indvidual=+(n%10); /* obtain a digit (+ is not required, but left by respect) */
  n/=10; /* eliminate last dight and proceed to next digit */
  sum+=invidual; /* use += instead of =+ */
}
printf("%d",sum); /* also add semicolon here */
return 0;
```

Comment: I'd also suggest to correct all the typos, and use the maximum warning level available to the compiler (also, there's still the problem of numbers with more than 5 digits)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 12345;
    int sum;
          
    i = abs(i);
    sum = i?i%9?i%9:9:0;

    printf ("Sum of digits is %d\n",  sum);
}
```

### Result is 6

Because `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15`
and then `1 + 5 = 6`

(or is the expected output `15`, after just a single pass through the digits?)

---

---

If you want only a single pass through the digits:

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 12345;
    int sum=0;
          
    i = abs(i);
    while(i)
    {
        sum += i%10;
        i /= 10;
    }

    printf ("Sum of digits is %d\n",  sum);
    return 0;
}
```